# Generate OData VDM using S/4 HANA SDK leads to errors

Tags: s4sdk

I tried to generate VDM for the OData service provided by S/4 HANA Cloud (which is not in API hub). The generated VDM class shows errors, in particular, it has an error with UUID set and get method, and the TRUE property. I attached the metadata edmx.xml here.

Ying

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

edmx.xml:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData" Version="1.0">
<edmx:Reference xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Uri="https://my300470-api.s4hana.ondemand.com/sap/opu/odata/IWFND/CATALOGSERVICE;v=2/Vocabularies(TechnicalName='%2FIWBEP%2FVOC_COMMON',Version='0001',SAP__Origin='LOCAL')/$value">
<edmx:Include Namespace="com.sap.vocabularies.Common.v1" Alias="Common"/>
</edmx:Reference>
<edmx:Reference xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Uri="https://my300470-api.s4hana.ondemand.com/sap/opu/odata/IWFND/CATALOGSERVICE;v=2/Vocabularies(TechnicalName='%2FIWBEP%2FVOC_CAPABILITIES',Version='0001',SAP__Origin='LOCAL')/$value">
<edmx:Include Namespace="Org.OData.Capabilities.V1" Alias="Capabilities"/>
</edmx:Reference>
<edmx:Reference xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Uri="https://my300470-api.s4hana.ondemand.com/sap/opu/odata/IWFND/CATALOGSERVICE;v=2/Vocabularies(TechnicalName='%2FIWBEP%2FVOC_COMMUNICATION',Version='0001',SAP__Origin='LOCAL')/$value">
<edmx:Include Namespace="com.sap.vocabularies.Communication.v1" Alias="Communication"/>
</edmx:Reference>
<edmx:Reference xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Uri="https://my300470-api.s4hana.ondemand.com/sap/opu/odata/IWFND/CATALOGSERVICE;v=2/Vocabularies(TechnicalName='%2FIWBEP%2FVOC_AGGREGATION',Version='0001',SAP__Origin='LOCAL')/$value">
<edmx:Include Namespace="Org.OData.Aggregation.V1" Alias="Aggregation"/>
</edmx:Reference>
<edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="2.0">
<Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm" Namespace="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV" xml:lang="en" sap:schema-version="1">
<EntityType Name="IagprivilegeauthDetails" sap:content-version="1">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="BusinessCatalogID"/>
<PropertyRef Name="PrivilegeRole"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="BusinessCatalogID" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" sap:unicode="false" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="PrivilegeRole" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" sap:unicode="false" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="PrivilegeProfile" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" sap:unicode="false" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="ActionType" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" sap:unicode="false" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="AuthGroup" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" sap:unicode="false" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="ResourceId" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" sap:unicode="false" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="ResourceExtn" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" sap:unicode="false" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="FromValue" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" sap:unicode="false" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="ToValue" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" sap:unicode="false" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="FioriCatalogId" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" sap:unicode="false" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
</EntityType>
<EntityType Name="aps_iam_brbua_ddlType" sap:label="Business Role Business User Assignment" sap:content-version="1">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="BusinessRoleUUID"/>
<PropertyRef Name="BusinessUserAssignmentID"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="BusinessRoleUUID" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false" sap:label="Business Role UUID"/>
<Property Name="BusinessUserAssignmentID" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="12" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Business User Assignment ID"/>
<Property Name="UserID" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="12" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Business User ID"/>
<Property Name="UserName" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="40" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Business User Name"/>
<Property Name="FirstName" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="40" sap:label="Business User First Name"/>
<Property Name="LastName" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="40" sap:label="Business User Last Name"/>
<Property Name="PersonID" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="10" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Business User Person ID"/>
<Property Name="Building" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="10" sap:label="Building"/>
<Property Name="Floor" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="10" sap:label="Floor"/>
<Property Name="Room" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="10" sap:label="Room"/>
<Property Name="PriceCategory" Type="Edm.Int16" sap:label="Price Category"/>
<Property Name="PriceCategoryText" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="80" sap:label="Price Category"/>
</EntityType>
<EntityType Name="Aps_Iam_Siag_Brca_DllType" sap:label="Business Role - Catalog Assignment" sap:content-version="1">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="ID"/>
<PropertyRef Name="BusinessCatalogID"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="ID" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Bus. Role ID" sap:quickinfo="IAM: Business Role ID"/>
<Property Name="BusinessCatalogID" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="35" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Catalog ID" sap:quickinfo="IAM: Business Catalog ID"/>
<Property Name="BusinessRoleUUID" Type="Edm.Guid" sap:label="UUID" sap:quickinfo="Global Unique ID for table"/>
<Property Name="FioriCatalogID" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="35" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Fiori Catalog ID" sap:quickinfo="Fiori Catalog Type"/>
<Property Name="RoleTemplate" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="30" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Role Name"/>
<Property Name="Restrictable" Type="Edm.Boolean" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Restrictable"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="to_BusinessRole" Relationship="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.assoc_7D2C2868538CD70C0B433A90421C523F" FromRole="FromRole_assoc_7D2C2868538CD70C0B433A90421C523F" ToRole="ToRole_assoc_7D2C2868538CD70C0B433A90421C523F"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="to_Description" Relationship="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.assoc_C2CAEB0FCF842BFF92ECFB837B9001F9" FromRole="FromRole_assoc_C2CAEB0FCF842BFF92ECFB837B9001F9" ToRole="ToRole_assoc_C2CAEB0FCF842BFF92ECFB837B9001F9"/>
</EntityType>
<EntityType Name="Aps_Iam_Siag_Br_DllType" sap:label="IAG Business Role View" sap:content-version="1">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="ID"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="ID" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Bus. Role ID" sap:quickinfo="IAM: Business Role ID"/>
<Property Name="UUID" Type="Edm.Guid" sap:label="UUID" sap:quickinfo="Global Unique ID for table"/>
<Property Name="LastChangedAt" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Precision="0" sap:label="Time Stamp" sap:quickinfo="UTC Time Stamp in Short Form (YYYYMMDDhhmmss)"/>
<Property Name="LastChangedBy" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="12" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="User Name"/>
<Property Name="Description" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="80" sap:label="" sap:quickinfo="IAM: Business Role Description"/>
<Property Name="Language" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="2" sap:label="Language Key"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="to_BusinessCatalogAssignment" Relationship="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.assoc_DFC7845EA2C63AB8EE73721D41279674" FromRole="FromRole_assoc_DFC7845EA2C63AB8EE73721D41279674" ToRole="ToRole_assoc_DFC7845EA2C63AB8EE73721D41279674"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="to_BusinessUserAssignment" Relationship="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.assoc_35A670E810662891BAABAA62A25B742F" FromRole="FromRole_assoc_35A670E810662891BAABAA62A25B742F" ToRole="ToRole_assoc_35A670E810662891BAABAA62A25B742F"/>
</EntityType>
<EntityType Name="aps_iam_vbct_ddlType" sap:label="Business Catalog Text" sap:content-version="1">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="bu_catalog_id"/>
<PropertyRef Name="language"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="bu_catalog_id" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="35" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Catalog ID" sap:quickinfo="IAM: Business Catalog ID"/>
<Property Name="language" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="2" sap:label="Language Key"/>
<Property Name="text" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="80" sap:label="Business Catalog"/>
<Property Name="long_text" Type="Edm.String" sap:label="Description" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="is_deprecated" Type="Edm.Boolean" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="TRUE" sap:quickinfo="Data element for domain BOOLE: TRUE (='X') and FALSE (=' ')"/>
</EntityType>
<Association Name="assoc_C2CAEB0FCF842BFF92ECFB837B9001F9" sap:content-version="1">
<End Type="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.Aps_Iam_Siag_Brca_DllType" Multiplicity="1" Role="FromRole_assoc_C2CAEB0FCF842BFF92ECFB837B9001F9"/>
<End Type="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.aps_iam_vbct_ddlType" Multiplicity="*" Role="ToRole_assoc_C2CAEB0FCF842BFF92ECFB837B9001F9"/>
</Association>
<Association Name="assoc_7D2C2868538CD70C0B433A90421C523F" sap:content-version="1">
<End Type="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.Aps_Iam_Siag_Brca_DllType" Multiplicity="1" Role="FromRole_assoc_7D2C2868538CD70C0B433A90421C523F"/>
<End Type="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.Aps_Iam_Siag_Br_DllType" Multiplicity="0..1" Role="ToRole_assoc_7D2C2868538CD70C0B433A90421C523F"/>
</Association>
<Association Name="assoc_DFC7845EA2C63AB8EE73721D41279674" sap:content-version="1">
<End Type="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.Aps_Iam_Siag_Br_DllType" Multiplicity="1" Role="FromRole_assoc_DFC7845EA2C63AB8EE73721D41279674"/>
<End Type="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.Aps_Iam_Siag_Brca_DllType" Multiplicity="*" Role="ToRole_assoc_DFC7845EA2C63AB8EE73721D41279674"/>
</Association>
<Association Name="assoc_35A670E810662891BAABAA62A25B742F" sap:content-version="1">
<End Type="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.Aps_Iam_Siag_Br_DllType" Multiplicity="1" Role="FromRole_assoc_35A670E810662891BAABAA62A25B742F"/>
<End Type="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.aps_iam_brbua_ddlType" Multiplicity="*" Role="ToRole_assoc_35A670E810662891BAABAA62A25B742F"/>
</Association>
<EntityContainer Name="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV_Entities" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true" sap:supported-formats="atom json xlsx">
<EntitySet Name="IagprivilegeauthDetailsSet" EntityType="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.IagprivilegeauthDetails" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:searchable="true" sap:content-version="1"/>
<EntitySet Name="aps_iam_brbua_ddl" EntityType="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.aps_iam_brbua_ddlType" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:content-version="1"/>
<EntitySet Name="Aps_Iam_Siag_Brca_Dll" EntityType="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.Aps_Iam_Siag_Brca_DllType" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:content-version="1"/>
<EntitySet Name="Aps_Iam_Siag_Br_Dll" EntityType="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.Aps_Iam_Siag_Br_DllType" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:content-version="1"/>
<EntitySet Name="aps_iam_vbct_ddl" EntityType="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.aps_iam_vbct_ddlType" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:content-version="1"/>
<AssociationSet Name="assoc_35A670E810662891BAABAA62A25B742F" Association="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.assoc_35A670E810662891BAABAA62A25B742F" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:content-version="1">
<End EntitySet="Aps_Iam_Siag_Br_Dll" Role="FromRole_assoc_35A670E810662891BAABAA62A25B742F"/>
<End EntitySet="aps_iam_brbua_ddl" Role="ToRole_assoc_35A670E810662891BAABAA62A25B742F"/>
</AssociationSet>
<AssociationSet Name="assoc_7D2C2868538CD70C0B433A90421C523F" Association="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.assoc_7D2C2868538CD70C0B433A90421C523F" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:content-version="1">
<End EntitySet="Aps_Iam_Siag_Brca_Dll" Role="FromRole_assoc_7D2C2868538CD70C0B433A90421C523F"/>
<End EntitySet="Aps_Iam_Siag_Br_Dll" Role="ToRole_assoc_7D2C2868538CD70C0B433A90421C523F"/>
</AssociationSet>
<AssociationSet Name="assoc_C2CAEB0FCF842BFF92ECFB837B9001F9" Association="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.assoc_C2CAEB0FCF842BFF92ECFB837B9001F9" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:content-version="1">
<End EntitySet="Aps_Iam_Siag_Brca_Dll" Role="FromRole_assoc_C2CAEB0FCF842BFF92ECFB837B9001F9"/>
<End EntitySet="aps_iam_vbct_ddl" Role="ToRole_assoc_C2CAEB0FCF842BFF92ECFB837B9001F9"/>
</AssociationSet>
<AssociationSet Name="assoc_DFC7845EA2C63AB8EE73721D41279674" Association="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.assoc_DFC7845EA2C63AB8EE73721D41279674" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:content-version="1">
<End EntitySet="Aps_Iam_Siag_Br_Dll" Role="FromRole_assoc_DFC7845EA2C63AB8EE73721D41279674"/>
<End EntitySet="Aps_Iam_Siag_Brca_Dll" Role="ToRole_assoc_DFC7845EA2C63AB8EE73721D41279674"/>
</AssociationSet>
<FunctionImport Name="getBusinessCatalogAuthDetails" ReturnType="Collection(APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.IagprivilegeauthDetails)" EntitySet="IagprivilegeauthDetailsSet" m:HttpMethod="GET" sap:action-for="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.IagprivilegeauthDetails">
<Parameter Name="BusinessCatalogID" Type="Edm.String" Mode="In" MaxLength="40"/>
<Parameter Name="ID" Type="Edm.String" Mode="In" MaxLength="40"/>
</FunctionImport>
<FunctionImport Name="getAuthDetails" ReturnType="Collection(APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.IagprivilegeauthDetails)" EntitySet="IagprivilegeauthDetailsSet" m:HttpMethod="GET" sap:action-for="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.IagprivilegeauthDetails">
<Parameter Name="ID" Type="Edm.String" Mode="In"/>
</FunctionImport>
</EntityContainer>
<Annotations xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Target="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV_Entities">
<Annotation Term="Aggregation.ApplySupported">
<Record>
<PropertyValue Property="Transformations">
<Collection>
<String>aggregate</String>
<String>groupby</String>
<String>filter</String>
</Collection>
</PropertyValue>
<PropertyValue Property="Rollup" EnumMember="None"/>
</Record>
</Annotation>
</Annotations>
<Annotations xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Target="APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV.APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV_Entities/aps_iam_vbct_ddl">
<Annotation Term="Capabilities.FilterRestrictions">
<Record>
<PropertyValue Property="FilterExpressionRestrictions">
<Collection>
<Record>
<PropertyValue Property="Property" PropertyPath="long_text"/>
<PropertyValue Property="AllowedExpressions" String="SearchExpression"/>
</Record>
</Collection>
</PropertyValue>
<PropertyValue Property="NonFilterableProperties">
<Collection>
<PropertyPath>long_text</PropertyPath>
</Collection>
</PropertyValue>
</Record>
</Annotation>
<Annotation Term="Capabilities.SortRestrictions">
<Record>
<PropertyValue Property="NonSortableProperties">
<Collection>
<PropertyPath>long_text</PropertyPath>
<PropertyPath>long_text</PropertyPath>
</Collection>
</PropertyValue>
</Record>
</Annotation>
</Annotations>
<atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="self" href="https://my300470-api.s4hana.ondemand.com/sap/opu/odata/SAP/APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV/$metadata"/>
<atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="latest-version" href="https://my300470-api.s4hana.ondemand.com/sap/opu/odata/SAP/APS_IAM_SIAG_BROLE_SRV/$metadata"/>
</Schema>
</edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx> `
```

Comment: Can you please clarify which errors you encounter? I basically followed the [deep dive](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/04/30/deep-dive-10-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-generating-java-vdm-for-s4hana-custom-odata-service/), incl. adding the necessary dependencies (like lombok), and it looks fine for me. On an additional note: You might want to consider cleaning the labels/names up so that e.g. the `is_deprecated` property is not exposed as `getTRUE`.

Comment: Hi Christoph, Thanks for quick response!
I sent an e-mail with screen shot.
Please look at  the screen shot, the code generated for IAGBusinessRoleView.java.
If you look at the left panel,  you don’t see the getter methods, but in the source code at the right side, the getter methods are needed in the generated code.
I don’t know why two set of properties are generated. I am not sure if it is related to this.
The Odata service is provided by S/4 HANA colleagues. I can see it needs to be improved with labels. But I can’t change them because it is not our code.

Best regards

Fred

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the problem was missing Lombok configuration.

As this question is asked multiple times I will give a bit more comprehensive answer than just "configure it", answering the most common questions.

### What is Lombok?

According to their [website](https://projectlombok.org/):

> Project Lombok is a java library that automatically plugs into your editor and build tools, spicing up your java.
>   Never write another getter or equals method again, with one annotation your class has a fully featured builder, Automate your logging variables, and much more.

More specifically Lombok allows you to add annotations to your code which will generate boilerplate at compile time.

So, taking [`@EqualsAndHashCode`](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode) as an example: This will generate, as the name implies, valid `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()` methods for the annotated class.

See the [overview page](https://projectlombok.org/features/all) for a full list of annotations.

### What are you using Lombok for?

We use the following annotations in our OData VDM Generator (not a full list, this might also change in the future):

- [`@Builder`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder)
- [`@ToString`](https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString)
- [`@EqualsAndHashCode`](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode)
- [`@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data)

The last annotation brings in, besides others, the [`@Getter`](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter) annotation which generates all necessary getters at compile time.

### How do I compile my code with Lombok/Display it in my IDE?

As described directly by [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven) and our [blog post](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/04/30/deep-dive-10-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-generating-java-vdm-for-s4hana-custom-odata-service/) you just need the Lombok dependency (`org.projectlombok:lombok`) with scope `provided` on your classpath.

To view the code in your IDE without any build issues you need to setup your IDE accordingly, see the [Lombok guides](https://projectlombok.org/setup/overview) for that.