# How to send Function Import request via S/4HANA SDK?

Tags: s4sdk

I know we can use classes ODataXXXRequestBuilders to issue "CUD" ODATA operations, but how about "Function Import"? Regarding a custom "Function Import" ODATA API, how to use S/4HANA SDK to issue the request and get the returned result? I cannot find any example for this. Or is it not supported? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question I can derive that you use the [SAP Cloud Platform SDK for Service Development](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/03/01/sap-cloud-platform-sdk-for-service-development-overview-of-blogs/).

In order to invoke functions imports in a convenient manner, we recommend to use the Virtual Data Model (VDM) for OData provided by the [SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/05/10/first-steps-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk/).

Leveraging this VDM you call OData APIs (including function imports) in a type-safe manner. You may check out [the introduction to the VDM](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/11/step-10-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-virtual-data-model-for-odata/) and the [deep dive focusing on custom OData services](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/04/30/deep-dive-10-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-generating-java-vdm-for-s4hana-custom-odata-service/).

Comment: Hi Emdee, thanks very much for the reply. In fact, I also tried the way of VDM. However, I can generate the VDM code successfully but there are too many syntax errors in the generated source code. I have no idea how to trouble shoot these syntax errors, any tips for that?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55118431/3275009).

Comment: In case the answer provided by Christoph does not help, kindly create another question to address these syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks very much, Christoph, it really helps.